# How to hide what we did in javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, function

How to hide what we did in javascript functions?
I mean Instead Of

```
function alpha(){
  var a=Math.PI;
  //other stuff
  return a;
}

alpha();//= a
alpha;//=function alpha(){...}
```

Be

```
alpha;//='presetted function placeholder'
```

[Chrome Functions Also Following This](https://gist.github.com/esdmr/df439e8796863d63160790c528b7145a#file-chrome-functions-js-L1625). Example:

- `$ == function $(selector, [startNode]){ [Command Line API] }`
- `return "function " + name + "(" + funcArgsSyntax + ") { [Command Line API] }";`

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: google obfuscation if that is what you mean.

Comment: @esdmr, you've described *what* you want it for, but not **why** you want this functionality. This appears to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @zzzzBov for protection.i dont care about browser compatibility.

Comment: @esdmr, protection from what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Chrome is doing here is setting a custom `toString` method in these functions. Using your example:

```
function alpha(){
}
a.toString = function() {
    return 'presetted function placeholder';
};
```

Then if you were to enter `alpha` in the console, in Chrome you would see:

```
function presetted function placeholder
```

**Note:** This doesn't really "hide" the code in any secure fashion, you could just use `Function.prototype.toString.call(alpha)` to get the default `toString` behavior.